# Topological Join of Unit Balls

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have seen that apparently one has for spheres that $S^n*S^m=S^{n+m+1}$. Is there a similar result for unit balls?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please, in particular what does the asterisk mean here?

Comment: I am sorry, I thought the notation was well known. For topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ we define X*Y=[0,1]\times X \times Y / \sim, wehere $(0,x_1,y)\sim (0,x_2,y)$ and $(1,x,y_1) \sim(1,x,y_2)$. I wonder if for $B^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and  $B^m \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ we have $B^n*B^m=B^{n+m+1}$ or something along those lines

Comment: That's fine I'm just trying to help clarify because they are voting to close your question.  I voted to keep it open but obviously somebody here thinks it needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

if you take simplexes instead of balls, it's easy to see that $\Delta^m*\Delta^n=\Delta^{m+n+1}$. one can prove it by induction, using $\Delta^m*pt=\Delta^{m+1}$ and the fact that join operation is associative.